# PHP inserting into database

Tags: php, sql, database, checkbox

Hey guys, im trying to insert some checkboxes into a database and im pretty sure my code is correct however i keep getting the error `ERROR INSERTING: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Basically i am adding each checkbox to a different column in my database

Here is my code

```
    $idextra=$_POST['extras'];
    $arr_num=count($idextra);
    $i=0;
    while ($i < $arr_num)
   {

    $qu="INSERT INTO bs_reservations (deodoriser,carpet,carpetrepair,furniture,tabs,urine) VALUES ('$idextra[$i]')";
    $res=mysql_query($qu) or die('ERROR INSERTING: '.mysql_error());
      $i++;
    }
```

Hey guys here is the HTML for my check boxes and contact form.

`

```
          <tr>
            <td height="30" align="right" class="align_right">Your Name*:&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name?>"  onchange="checkFieldBack(this)"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="30" align="right" class="align_right">Phone*:&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo $phone?>"  onchange="checkFieldBack(this)" onkeyup="noAlpha(this)"/></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td height="30" align="right" class="align_right">E-mail*:&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"  value="<?php echo $email?>" onchange="checkFieldBack(this);"/></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td align="right"  valign="top" class="align_right">Address*:&nbsp;</td>
            <td><textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="15" rows="5" onchange="checkFieldBack(this)"><?php echo $comments?></textarea></td>
          </tr>

    <tr>
<td width="236" height="25" align="left">Drop off at:</td>
<td width="548" height="23"><select name="dropoff">

             <option value="05:00" <?php echo $dropoff=="05:00"?"selected":""?>>05:00</option>
             <option value="06:00" <?php echo $dropoff=="06:00"?"selected":""?>>06:00</option>
             <option value="07:00" <?php echo $dropoff=="07:00"?"selected":""?>>07:00</option>
             <option value="08:00" <?php echo $dropoff=="08:00"?"selected":""?>>08:00</option>
             <option value="09:00" <?php echo $dropoff=="09:00"?"selected":""?>>09:00</option>                      
             <option value="10:00" <?php echo $dropoff=="10:00"?"selected":""?>>10:00</option>
             <option value="11:00" <?php echo $dropoff=="11:00"?"selected":""?>>11:00</option>
             <option value="12:00" <?php echo $dropoff=="12:00"?"selected":""?>>12:00</option>
             <option value="13:00" <?php echo $dropoff=="13:00"?"selected":""?>>13:00</option>
             <option value="14:00" <?php echo $dropoff=="14:00"?"selected":""?>>14:00</option>
             <option value="15:00" <?php echo $dropoff=="15:00"?"selected":""?>>15:00</option>
             <option value="16:00" <?php echo $dropoff=="16:00"?"selected":""?>>16:00</option>
             <option value="17:00" <?php echo $dropoff=="17:00"?"selected":""?>>17:00</option>
             <option value="18:00" <?php echo $dropoff=="18:00"?"selected":""?>>18:00</option>
             <option value="19:00" <?php echo $dropoff=="19:00"?"selected":""?>>19:00</option>


  </select> 
      </td>
```

```
    <tr>
            <td height="10" align="right" class="align_right">Deodoriser:&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name="extras[]" id="deodoriser" value="Deodoriser>"/>
            </td>
          </tr>

<tr>
            <td height="30" align="right" class="align_right">Carpet Protector (5 litre):&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name="extras[]" id="carpet" value="Carpet Protector (5 litre)"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
<tr>
            <td height="30" align="right" class="align_right">Carpet Repair Tools:&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name="extras[]" id="carpetrepair" value="Carpet Repair Tools"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
<tr>
            <td height="30" align="right" class="align_right">Furniture Moving Equipment:&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name="extras[]" id="furniture" value="Furniture Moving Equipment"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
<tr>
            <td height="30" align="right" class="align_right">Furniture Tabs:&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name="extras[]" id="tabs" value="Furniture Tabs"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
<tr>
            <td height="30" align="right" class="align_right">Urine Decontamination Treatment:&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name="extras[]" id="urine" value="Urine Decontamination Treatment"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
```

`

and here is my complete php code for inserting into the data base

`$idextra=$_POST['extras'];
    $arr_num=count($idextra);
    $i=0;
    while ($i < $arr_num)
   {

```
$qu="INSERT INTO bs_reservations (deodoriser,carpet,carpetrepair,furniture,tabs,urine) VALUES ('{$idextra[1]}','{$idextra[2]}','{$idextra[3]}','{$idextra[4]}','{$idextra[5]}','{$idextra[6]}')";
$res=mysql_query($qu) or die('ERROR INSERTING: '.mysql_error());
  $i++;
}


$q="INSERT INTO bs_reservations (dateCreated, name, email, phone, comments,status,eventID, qty,dropoff) VALUES (NOW(),'".$name."','".$email."','".$phone."','".$comments."','2','".$eventID."','".$qty."','".$dropoff."')";
$res=mysql_query($q) or die("error!");
$orderID=mysql_insert_id();`
```

I basically want to take all the inputs that the user selects and insert them into a data base.

Comment: this is problem bz values are not separated by comma ',' ??

Comment: I love how there is no validation/sanitize for the bare `$_POST` vars too ;)

Comment: Sorry, but your code is _not_ correct. You're doing exactly what mysql is crying about. if you tell us what you're trying to do we can help you

Comment: Can you paste your html code to produce checkboxes here ? btw, you are only counting values that expected to be posted by the correct order which can lead you a serious/continous problem when html form code has been changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have these columns:

```
(deodoriser,carpet,carpetrepair,furniture,tabs,urine)
```

And you are inserting this:

```
'$idextra[$i]'
```

That's 6 columns and 1 value. As the error says, that's not the same.

You might have meant something like this:

```
('{$idextra[1]}','{$idextra[2]}','{$idextra[3]}','{$idextra[4]}','{$idextra[5]}','{$idextra[6]}')
```

If you want to make a string out of your array beforehand, use something like this using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$yourString = implode("','",$idextra);
$qu="INSERT INTO bs_reservations (deodoriser,carpet,carpetrepair,furniture,tabs,urine)
      VALUES ('{$yourString}')";
```

`echo` the query to be sure it's sane :)

Comment: doing this works, however there are 6 check boxes and if the customer only selects say the first 2 and the last, when inserting into the database it inserts the last checkbox into the 3rd column

Comment: A trick for the checkboxes is this: add a hidden field/input with value 0 BEFORE your checkbox. If it is checked, your value is overwritten by the second field, and gets a 1 (or true). If the second isn't checked, it is ignored by the form, but the first (hidden) one isn't, so it passes its 0. presto, 6 values, everybody happy :D

Comment: how do i add a "hidden value" just add a value ='0'

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="Name" value="0"/>`

Comment: does the input type not have to be checkbox?

Comment: Maybe you need to try some stuff out because of the array: you can name them seperately maybe, or else you might get extra values. At least the cause of the error is found :). If you go all-out you can just check for separate names instead of an array for checkboxes?

Comment: will do, thanks heaps for your help i have been stumped for ages :)

Comment: @Simon do not use sql injection-vulnerable solutions, use safe ones.

Comment: shrapnel is right, though offtopic. It will not help you with your current problem, but indeed you might want to look into SQL injections. But seeing that the code will be probably larger then just this issue, that is not the topic here, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using array for your checkboxes, give them distinct names, e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="carpetrepair" id="carpetrepair" value="Carpet Repair Tools"/>
```

And then check if any of them were checked:

```
$options = explode(",","deodoriser,carpet,carpetrepair,furniture,tabs,urine");
$sql = "INSERT INTO bs_reservations SET ";
foreach($options as $opt){
  if (isset($_POST[$opt])) {
    $sql.= "`$opt`=1,";
  }
}
$sql = rtrim($sql,",");
```

Comment: sorry to be so late mate but just wondering how this actually works. Will it actually assign each variable a name and insert it into the data base or do i need to addmore code